# Proving that intersection number of divisor is 0

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, intersection-theory, divisors-algebraic-geometry

My question arises from proposition 8.3 in the algebraic geometry text by Shigeru Iitaka:

Let $f:W\rightarrow S$ be a surjective morphism between nonsingular projective surfaces. Let $E$ be a divisor on $W$ such that $f(E) =p$ is a point. Then for any divisor $D$ on $S$, one has their intersection number on $W$: $(f^*D, E)_W=0$.

Here is the proof the author gave:

Basically we want to show that $(f^*D,E)_W =\operatorname{deg}(\mathcal{O}(f^*D)|_E)$ is zero. The author claims that $\mathcal{O}(f^*D)|_E \cong \mathcal{O}_E$ and it is proven as follows:

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{O}(f^*D)|_E & = (f^* (\mathcal{O}(D))|_E \\
& = f|_E^* (\mathcal{O}(D)|_p)  \quad \quad - \star \\
& \cong \mathcal{O}_E \quad \quad -\star\star
\end{align*}

Where $f|_E:E\rightarrow \{p\}$ denotes the restriction of $f$ to $E$. I am lost at the steps labelled ‘$\star$‘ and ‘$\star\star$’

Q1) What exactly does $\mathcal{O}(D)|_p$ mean in this context? I believe you need to restrict to a divisor on $S$. But $\{p\}$ is a point in $S$ and so restricting to just merely $’p’$ does not make any sense. Given that this restriction makes sense, then do we jump from the preceding step to $\star$?

Q2) Naturally, I am unable to understand how $\star\star$ is derived, i.e. why is the preceding line isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_E$.

I believe if I understand how $\star$ is derived I will be able to work out the rest. Would greatly appreciate any help given! Thank you, and wishing you guys a happy new year. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at $f^*(\mathcal{O}(D))|_E$, we're pulling back $\mathcal{O}(D)$ along the two maps $E\to W\to S$, and because this composition $E\to S$ factors through $\{p\}$, it will equal the pullback of $\mathcal{O}(D)$ along $E\to \{p\} \to S$, which is what's going on in the first starred step.

In the second starred step, we're just using the fact that $\mathcal{O}(D)|_p$ is a line bundle on a point, so it's trivial, and pulling it back to $E$ again gives the trivial line bundle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I understand your answer. Just to clarify, my understanding of $f^*(\mathcal{O}(D))|_E*$ means you tensor $f^*(\mathcal{O}(D)\otimes \mathcal{O}_E$. Are you implying that this is just $i^*(f^*\mathcal{O}(D))$ where $i:E\rightarrow W$ is the closed immersion?

Comment: @thedilated Yes – more precisely, $f^*(\mathcal{O}(D))|_E$ is the tensor product $i^{-1}(f^*(\mathcal{O}(D))\otimes_{i^{-1}\mathcal{O}_W}\mathcal{O}_E$, which is the definition of $i^*(f^*(\mathcal{O}(D)))$.

Comment: Thank you very much. May I ask one more question (hope you don’t mind.. ) Writing $\mathcal{F} = f^*\mathcal{O}(D)$ for convenience, we have established that $\mathcal{F}|_E = i_E* \mathcal{F}$, where $i_E: E\rightarrow W$ is the closed immersion. However, for a general invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L} = \mathcal{O}_W(D)$ on $W$, the restriction $\mathcal{L}|_E$ is taken to be just $\mathcal{L} \otimes \mathcal{O}_E$ instead. May I ask if $i^*\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{L}|_E$ are actually identical in this case? (Because the author seem to use this interchangeable and its not obvious to me)

Comment: @thedilated I see – that definition of the restriction strikes me as very strange: without all the $i^{-1}$'s, I take this to mean that $\mathcal{O}_E$ is being viewed as a sheaf on all of $W$ (albeit supported only on $E$), and the resulting tensor product taken over $\mathcal{O}_W$ to yield a sheaf on $W$, so these are not literally identical in this case. Morally the result is the same, since we can restrict to the support without losing anything, but I'm not sure it's standard. (1/2)

Comment: @thedilated The problem is that Iitaka really is treating this like it's a sheaf on $E$: your first starred equality is $(f^*\mathcal{O}(D))|_E=f|_E^*(\mathcal{O}(D)|_p)$, and the sheaf on the right is a sheaf on $E$, so we should expect the one on the left to be a sheaf on $E$ as well. In my experience, when one talks about the restriction of a sheaf to a subset $i:Z\to X$, they usually mean a sheaf on that subset (using the inverse image sheaf in general, and the pullback sheaf in the quasicoherent case, via tensoring over $i^{-1}\mathcal{O}_X$ with $\mathcal{O}_Z$). (2/2)